# Opencart 3.0.2.0 and Journal 3 theme customer name in Top Menu

Tags: opencart, customization

I want to add customer first name on Journal theme top menu module. I am adding `{{ text_logged }}` in top-menu.twig but it can not get text_logged from controller. How can I get text_logged from catalog/controller/common/header.php?

```
{% if logged %}
   {{ text_logged }}
{% endif %}

$data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', true), $this->customer->getFirstName(), $this->url->link('account/logout', '', true));
```

I want to see "Hello John Do" on Journal theme top menu $ US Dollar instead

Comment: You should ask developers of Journal theme. They must to give full support. Because theme is paid.

Comment: I'm using OpenCart 3.0.3.6 on Journal 3.1.14, and it's worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your code using ocmod or vqmod to the Journal theme common/header.tpl. I highly recommend do not change the Journal's core codes because of ridiculous cache system (even devs couldn't get rid of it). Also here is a solution : [You can edit this one for your purpose](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=34846)

Comment: Many thanks Serkan. I edited this mod and I replaced currency variable with customer_firstname variable in Journal Top Menu twig instead of header twigs and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had contacted the developer regarding the same issue for the journal theme v3. They told me that it can be displayed using this:

```
Welcome back, {{ $customer_firstname }} {{ $customer_lastname }} !
```

[image: screenshot of the method]
to show customer firstname and lastname in menu items.

I have integrated that into my code, and it now shows the customer name, when logged in. No need to edit OC MOD