# Logged in User first name on top Journal 3 Theme Opencart 3.0.3.6 displays Raw Code

Tags: php, twig, opencart

With reference to this link about this topic:
[Opencart 3.0.2.0 and Journal 3 theme customer name in Top Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689880/opencart-3-0-2-0-and-journal-3-theme-customer-name-in-top-menu/65515873#65515873)

@Johnson said  "I'm using OpenCart 3.0.3.6 on Journal 3.1.14, and it's worked."
I tried but it displays Raw code: {{$customer_firstname}} as it is.
Can some one help me how to display Logged in user's First Name  in top of pages in opencart 3.0.3.6 Journal Theme Version 3.1.5?
Thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it `{{ customer_firstname }}`
On twig file and also make sure you have passed it from controller file

```
If($this->customer-getFirstname())
 $data[‘customer_firstname’] = $this->customer->getFirstname();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `{{ customer_firstname }}` instead `{{$customer_firstname}}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I got it working by adding this:  {{ $customer_firstname }} {{ $customer_lastname }} ! to Journal theme Top menu->account section.